# How to use raw SQL query in EF Core get the expected result set in .net core

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, rawsql

I am trying to use raw SQL in .NET Core instead of normal EF Core approach.

Here is my query and what I am trying to do with it.

Entities used here are in a one-to-many relationship as one project can have multiple tasks:

```
public class Project : IId
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Reference { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
        public string ACode { get; set; }
        public string ICode { get; set; }
        public string Scheme { get; set; }
        public int? Ticket { get; set; }
        public DateTime Inception { get; set; }
        private StatusCalculator StatusCalculator { get; set; }
}

public class Task : IId
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore] public Project Project { get; set; }
        public Type Type { get; set; }
        public Status Status { get; private set; }
        public string CompletedBy { get; private set; }
        public DateTime? CompletedOn { get; private set; }
        public DateTime? Deadline { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; private set; }
        public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; private set; }
        public int? Ticket { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying following approach

```
public Project GetProject(string surname, string phone, string email, int page, int limit)
{
    var project = DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(string.Format($"SELECT P.ProjectId,P.Reference,P.CreatedOn,P.ACode,P.ICode,P.Scheme,P.Ticket,P.Inception,P.Status," +
                                                           "T.TaskId,T.ProjectId,T.Type,T.Status,T.CompletedBy,T.CompletedOn,T.Deadline,T.CreatedBy,T.CreatedOn,T.Ticket FROM TASK T " +
                                                           "INNER JOIN Project P ON P.ProjectId = T.ProjectId " +
                                                           "INNER JOIN CS26 C26 ON LEFT(C26.Bran,1) = LEFT(P.Branch,1) AND C26.Client = P.Client AND C26.Ref = P.Ref " +
                                                           "INNER JOIN A_C AC ON LEFT(AC.Bran,1) = LEFT(C26.Bran,1) AND AC.Client = C26.Client " +
                                                           "where AC.Surname = {0} and AC.Phone = {1} and C26.WEBADDR = {2} " +
                                                           "order by P.CreatedOn desc",surname,phone,email));

    return project;
}
```

but it seems that `ExecuteSqlRaw` returns only an `int` - I  need a way so I can use raw SQL and map the result returned to entities as shown above, so that expected result set can be obtained.

I need to fetch

```
Project -> Tasks array (existing tasks)
```

Comment: Have you looked at [SQL Queries - EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries) in the Microsoft docs? Pay close attention to the SQL injection warnings - but using `.FromSql` or `.FromSqlRaw` should allow you to fetch EF Core entities by using raw SQL statements

Comment: Why do you want to use raw queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the official documents, you will find

```
context.Blogs
.FromSql($"SELECT * FROM dbo.Blogs")
.ToList();
```

It is not suitable for complex multi-table query statements. `ExecuteSqlRaw` returns an instance of the int type, which determines whether the execution is complete.

#### EF Core is recommended

**If you still don't want, you can check the below content.**

If you don't want to use a third-party ORM framework, then you can consider using DataTable to receive the return results and convert them into the Entities you want.

Here is the sample I wrote before.

Github: [ISqlHelperService](https://github.com/Jason446620/AspNetCore7/blob/c3b63831c4b4edfa3f7043755898a32ca6ce87ec/Service/IService/ISqlHelperService.cs#L11)

And here is the method to convert `DataTable` to `List<T>`. Like below:

```
    public static List<T> ToListByDataTable<T>(DataTable dtTemp)
    {
        if (dtTemp == null || dtTemp.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        List<T> lstResult = new List<T>();

        for (int j = 0, l = dtTemp.Rows.Count; j < l; j++)
        {
            T _t = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
            PropertyInfo[] propertys = _t.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo pi in propertys)
            {
                for (int i = 0, k = dtTemp.Columns.Count; i < k; i++)
                {
                    if (pi.Name.ToLower().Equals(dtTemp.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToLower()))
                    {
                        if (dtTemp.Rows[j][i] != DBNull.Value)
                        {
                            switch (pi.PropertyType.ToString())
                            {
                                case "System.Int32":
                                    pi.SetValue(_t, int.Parse(dtTemp.Rows[j][i].ToString()), null);
                                    break;
                                case "System.Int64":
                                    pi.SetValue(_t, long.Parse(dtTemp.Rows[j][i].ToString()), null);
                                    break;
                                case "System.DateTime":
                                    pi.SetValue(_t, DateTime.Parse(dtTemp.Rows[j][i].ToString()), null);
                                    break;
                                case "System.String":
                                    pi.SetValue(_t, dtTemp.Rows[j][i].ToString(), null);
                                    break;
                                case "System.Boolean":
                                    pi.SetValue(_t, Boolean.Parse(dtTemp.Rows[j][i].ToString()), null);
                                    break;
                                case "System.Guid":
                                    pi.SetValue(_t, Guid.Parse(dtTemp.Rows[j][i].ToString()), null);
                                    break;
                                case "System.Single":
                                    pi.SetValue(_t, Convert.ToSingle(dtTemp.Rows[j][i].ToString()), null);
                                    break;
                                case "System.Double":
                                    pi.SetValue(_t, Convert.ToDouble(dtTemp.Rows[j][i].ToString()), null);
                                    break;
                                case "System.Object":
                                    pi.SetValue(_t, dtTemp.Rows[j][i], null);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            switch (pi.PropertyType.ToString())
                            {
                                case "System.Int32":
                                    pi.SetValue(_t, -1, null);
                                    break;
                                case "System.Int64":
                                    pi.SetValue(_t, -1, null);
                                    break;
                                case "System.DateTime":
                                    pi.SetValue(_t, new DateTime(0x76c, 1, 1), null);
                                    break;
                                case "System.Boolean":
                                    pi.SetValue(_t, false, null);
                                    break;
                                case "System.Guid":
                                    pi.SetValue(_t, Guid.Empty, null);
                                    break;
                                case "System.Single":
                                    pi.SetValue(_t, 0.0f, null);
                                    break;
                                case "System.Double":
                                    pi.SetValue(_t, 0.0, null);
                                    break;
                                case "System.String":
                                    pi.SetValue(_t, string.Empty, null);
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    pi.SetValue(_t, null, null);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            lstResult.Add(_t);
        }

        return lstResult;
    }
```